# How to use ifelse logic inside pressable element

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I am making a classic dialer for my project in react native. What I need to do is being able to switch colors of call button from red to green. Originally I was using images but I decided to change them to icons.

```
const volam = require("./assets/tlacitko_off.jpg");
const nevolam = require("./assets/tlacitko.png");

<View style = {styles.call_button}>
  <Pressable onPress={this.pressButton}>
    <Image style={styles.img}
     source={call == false ? nevolam : volam }
     />
  </Pressable>
</View>
```

Therefore I was able to switch between 2 different images one red and one green. Now I want to use `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhoneSquareAlt} color={'red'}/>`
and just switch between colors. I am no longer using an image so I cant just switch between sources and I  am trying to find a way how to implement this:

```
if(call == false){
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhoneSquareAlt} color={'green'}/>
}
else{
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhoneSquareAlt} color={'red'}/>
}
```

however I am unable to use ifelse logic inside a pressable element.
Could anyone please help me on how to use ifelse inside an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const colorName
colorName = call ? 'green' : 'red';
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhoneSquareAlt} color={colorName}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
<View style = {styles.call_button}>
  <Pressable onPress={this.pressButton}>
    { call == false ? 
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhoneSquareAlt} color={'green'}/> : 
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhoneSquareAlt} color={'red'}/>
    }
  </Pressable>
</View>
```